# My CS50 caesar program works fine but it doesn't pass check50

Tags: c, cs50

> This program is supposed to encrypt strings with the user's key. If the argument count is not 2 and the argv[1] (key) is not a positive number then it prints the usage instructions and returns 1.Else it does the rest of the program.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //Get the key
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int key = 0; key < strlen(argv[1]); key++)
    {
        if(isalpha(argv[1][key]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //Convert string to int
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    //Get the plaintext
    string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext:  ");

    //Output the ciphertext
    printf("ciphertext: ");

for (int i = 0, length = strlen(plaintext); i < length; i++)
{
    if(!isalpha(plaintext[i]))
    {
        printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        continue;
    }

    int offset = isupper(plaintext[i]);

    for (int j = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]) != 0)
        {
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]) != 0)
            {
                printf("%c", ((plaintext[i] - 65 + key) % 26) + 65);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", ((plaintext[i] - 97 + key) % 26) + 97);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        }
    }

    int p = plaintext[i] - offset;
    int c = (p + key) % 26;
    printf("%c", c + offset);
}

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

These are the check50 results:

```
:) caesar.c exists.
:) caesar.c compiles.
:( encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 as key
    expected "ciphertext: b\...", not "ciphertext: b\..."
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "yxocll" using 23 as key
    expected "ciphertext: yx...", not "ciphertext: yx..."
:( encrypts "BARFOO" as "EDUIRR" using 3 as key
    output not valid ASCII text
:( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key
    output not valid ASCII text
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "onesbb" using 65 as key
    expected "ciphertext: on...", not "ciphertext: on..."
:( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "iadxp, emk tqxxa!" using 12 as key
    expected "ciphertext: ia...", not "ciphertext: ia..."
:) handles lack of argv[1]
:) handles non-numeric key
:) handles too many arguments
```

But I can't figure out where's the problem. It literally says

> -expected "ciphertext: b...", not "ciphertext: b..."

They seem completely same to me.

Edit:

I've changed 65 and 97 to 'a' and 'A'.That solved the ASCII value problem.

I also removed this line.But the problems still remain.
`for (int j = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)`

**I've figured out everything and it passed the check50 tests.Thank you for all the help.My solution is below the comments.**

Comment: What happens if you inspect the failed results a bit closer? They normally show input data and result. Don't just look at the summary page

Comment: `if(isalpha(argv[1][key]))` Here `key` is a poor name as it is an index, not a key and `key` is defined a few lines later. Also you might switch to `!isdigit` instead of `isalpha` to avoid other unwanted characters.

Comment: Checking with `od -Ax -t x1`, your program is printing an extra `\x01` after `b` in the "input `a` with key 1" case.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)` Watch your variables...

Comment: Hmmm, the `for (int j = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)` loop doesn't look required for me.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use magic numbers like `65`, `97` and `26`. Use `'A'`, `'a'` and `lettercount = 'Z' - 'A' + 1` to make it clearer

Comment: Did you try running the program yourself a few times?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just did that and the ASCII problem is solved.Thank you.

Comment: @MikeCAT I see but how can I solve that problem?

Comment: Why do you need the inner loop? Your main loop is already iterating over the elements if `plaintext`, you don't need another loop for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend with `int offset = isupper(plaintext[i]);`. `offset` will contain either `0` or `1`, not an offset.

Comment: Regarding your latest addition to the question: _"I've figured out everything and it passed the check50 tests.Thank you for all the help."_ - If you think it'd be helpful to someone else with a similar problem, you are welcome to write an answer to your own question. That's perfectly ok and encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that things get complicated after the second for loop and I removed everything
`int offset = isupper(plaintext[i]);` 
to
`printf("%c", c + offset);`

And then I created a new function called `mix_text` and add that function with a `%s` in the line of printing ciphertext.This new function takes plaintext and key as its inputs and returns a string.Here's how it looks.

```
string mix_text(string plaintext, int key)
{
    string ciphertext = plaintext;
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(plaintext); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
        {
            ciphertext[i] = (plaintext[i] - 'A' + key) % 26 + 'A';
        }
        else if (islower(plaintext[i]))
        {
            ciphertext[i] = (plaintext[i] - 'a' + key) % 26 + 'a';
        }

    }
    return ciphertext;
```